# Python Splinter issue UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, splinter

I have used the same code for a couple of months without an issue, and now I have the following issue. Anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks

My `splinter` library is up-to-date, and I am using Chrome driver.

> ```sh
> File
> "C:\Users\isaks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py",
> line 90, in Browser
>     return get_driver(driver, *args, **kwargs)    File "C:\Users\isaks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py",
> line 68, in get_driver
>     raise e
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
> ```

Comment: Unhelpful error message. I had to download a new version of chromedriver to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This totally fixed it for me.  It's strange that somehow a new version of chromedriver somehow broke the old one cuz i had the exact same issue as you with one of my scripts and this is definitely not something I would have thought of